Estimating a minimal probability of detection to choose controls and cases
I have a dataset of cattle farms, the tests with results for bovine tuberculosis and the number of cattle tested and slaughtered. Meat inspection count as a test for bovine tuberculosis too.
I want to make a control-case study with the farms,not cattle in it, a positive/case farm is considered a farm that at least one bovine have a positive test.
The problem is the "surveillance pressure" or "the detection probability" is not homogeneus among the farms, neither the sample is random, so I want to choose controls and cases based on a minimal expected probability of detection to avoid analyse the outcome of farms that has too low probability of being detected, possibly resulting in a false negative if the disease is present.
In order to estimate the expected probability of detection of bovine tuberculosis positive farms, I formulated the following equation:

Where:
ePD represents the expected probability of detection of a positive animal given the farm is positive.
p represents the design or expected prevalence of BT within a positive herd/farm.
sid represents the sensitivity of the intradermal test.
sab represents the sensitivity of the slaughterhouse inspection.
i represents the number of intradermal tests
a represents the number of cattle inspected in slaugherhouse
My question now is how to choose the minimal value of ePD without being arbitrary? 0.5 seems to be a good value, but I need to statistically explain the logic behind it.
